# Axis2 wsdl2java throws InvocationTargetException and NullPointerException

Tags: java, soap, apache-axis

I'm having a problem with generating java src from wsdl(xml file) using axis2(tried this with versions 1.6.1-1.8.2): Using this cmd command

```
.\wsdl2java.bat -uri %PATH_TO_XML% -p org.apache.axis2.axis2userguide -d adb -s -u
```

I get:

```
Using AXIS2_HOME:   D:\Documentos\Axis\axis2-1.8.2
Using JAVA_HOME:    C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_271
Retrieving document at 'D:\Documentos\Axis\axis2-1.8.2\bin\ARIBankService.xml'.
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationEngine.generate(CodeGenerationEngine.java:163)
        at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.WSDL2Code.main(WSDL2Code.java:54)
        at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.WSDL2Java.main(WSDL2Java.java:24)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.extension.SimpleDBExtension.engage(SimpleDBExtension.java:53)
        at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationEngine.generate(CodeGenerationEngine.java:116)
        ... 2 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.extension.SimpleDBExtension.engage(SimpleDBExtension.java:50)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompilationException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.compile(SchemaCompiler.java:257)
        at org.apache.axis2.schema.ExtensionUtility.invoke(ExtensionUtility.java:102)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.addProcessedItemsToMetaInfoHolder(SchemaCompiler.java:2332)
        at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.process(SchemaCompiler.java:2152)
        at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processParticle(SchemaCompiler.java:2031)
        at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processComplexType(SchemaCompiler.java:1158)
        at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processNamedComplexSchemaType(SchemaCompiler.java:1088)
        at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processSchema(SchemaCompiler.java:998)
        at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processElement(SchemaCompiler.java:605)
        at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processElement(SchemaCompiler.java:573)
        at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.compile(SchemaCompiler.java:376)
        at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.compile(SchemaCompiler.java:268)
        at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.getParentSchemaFromIncludes(SchemaCompiler.java:2993)
        at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.getParentSchema(SchemaCompiler.java:2944)
        at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processElement(SchemaCompiler.java:819)
        at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processElement(SchemaCompiler.java:561)
        at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processElements(SchemaCompiler.java:2470)
        at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.process(SchemaCompiler.java:2146)
        at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processParticle(SchemaCompiler.java:2031)
        at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processComplexType(SchemaCompiler.java:1158)
        at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processNamedComplexSchemaType(SchemaCompiler.java:1088)
        at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processComplexContent(SchemaCompiler.java:1290)
        at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processContentModel(SchemaCompiler.java:1254)
        at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processComplexType(SchemaCompiler.java:1179)
        at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processNamedComplexSchemaType(SchemaCompiler.java:1088)
        at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processComplexContent(SchemaCompiler.java:1290)
        at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processContentModel(SchemaCompiler.java:1254)
        at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processComplexType(SchemaCompiler.java:1179)
        at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processNamedComplexSchemaType(SchemaCompiler.java:1088)
        at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processSchema(SchemaCompiler.java:998)
        at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processElement(SchemaCompiler.java:605)
        at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processElement(SchemaCompiler.java:573)
        at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.compile(SchemaCompiler.java:376)
        at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.compile(SchemaCompiler.java:248)
        ... 9 more
```

the wsdl (xml file) I'm using (I let the link 'cuz the file has to many characters):
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lLTsACW6jA9KSIaOTdoN0CKXyunLO4RR/view?usp=share_link

Expecting for the src to be created correctly to be able to consume the ws and translate it to another ws of REST type

Answer (score 0):

You're using "wsdl2java.bat" instead of "wsdl2java.sh" and "adb" instead of "xmlbeans".
Try this using the latest version 1.8.2: ".\wsdl2java.sh -uri $PATH_TO_XML -p org.apache.axis2.axis2userguide -d xmlbeans -s -u"